# Displaying in days using query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Sorry for bothering u guys again, I was looking for any other solution for my problem but i coundnt find one or perhaps am in a hurry. I have a table named "Employee"  with comlumns id, name, login, and logout.

like this

```
EmpID NAME  Login               Logout
0   t1     2013-04-11 01:00:00  2013-04-11 01:01:00
1   t2     2013-04-11 01:00:00  2013-04-11 01:01:00
2   t3     2013-04-11 01:00:00  2013-04-11 01:01:00
0   t1     2013-04-13 01:00:00  2013-04-13 01:01:00
1   t2     2013-04-14 01:00:00  2013-04-14 01:01:00
1   t2     2013-04-15 01:00:00  2013-04-15 01:01:00
2   t3     2013-04-15 01:00:00  2013-04-15 01:01:00
```

but i want to display the data like this

```
EmpID NAME    11            13          14                15
0   t1      60              60  
1   t2      60                           60               60
2   t3      60                                            60
```

Edited: The target display was already created on pivottable in MSaccess using from this query table code sample:

```
SELECT Employee.EmpID, Employee.EName, Sum(DateDiff("s",Punches.LogIN,Punches.LogOUT)) AS THours, day(Punches.LogIN) AS days
FROM Employee LEFT JOIN Punches ON Employee.EmpID = Punches.EmpID
GROUP BY Employee.EmpID, Employee.EName, day(Punches.LogIN)
ORDER BY Employee.EmpID;
```

could someone tell me how to use created pivottable in my program? like query?

ty

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for Access Pivot. This will do what you need.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i thought pivot works only in sql... like u said, i made a quick search for pivot in access... yes. there is sample and explanation. may be i will do some research again later after fixing my customers laptop. ty.. i will update this question later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an MS Access TRANSFORM/PIVOT to get the result. The basic syntax will be:

```
TRANSFORM max(datediff("n", login, logout))
SELECT id, name
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, name
PIVOT format(login, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: ty for the reply... in the meantime am trying to recreate the database with pivot.